# Hiding Navigation Button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a simple app that allows the user to select an image from their device via Camera Roll or to take a new image. Easy.

I have two buttons;

**1)** on the navigation bar named Set Image which saves the image to core data

**2)** on the main view that opens the image picker controller.

**My issue;**

How do I hide the button on the navigation bar if an image has ***not*** been selected?

[image]

```
    import UIKit

class CameraRollViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    }

    @IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Lets customize your Reminders Page", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{
                print("Camera not available")
            }


        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        imageView.image = image

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    }
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Add an outlet of Setimage button and show/hide it

Comment: UIBarButtonItem has no isHidden. Suggestions?

Comment: Add outlet to the UIButton inside UIBarButtonItem, if you don't have it, remove the existing bar button item and add a UIButton up there, it will work the same way and has all the functions.

Comment: Ah! Gotcha. Thanks Umar.

Comment: just Check that your ImageView.image is nil or not? if it's nil than hide button otherwise unhide button.